# how to join 2 dstream and window the joined stream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, datastax

i have 2 dstream in spark, i want to join the 2 streams first then compute the joined stream every 5 minutes for the last hour

i have tried:

1. `stream1.window(3600 * 1, 60 * 5).join(stream2.window(3600 * 1, 60 * 5)).foreachRDD(statistics)`
2. `stream1.window(3600 * 1, 60 * 5).join(stream2).foreachRDD(statistics)`
3. `stream1.join(stream2).window(3600 * 1, 60 * 5).foreachRDD(statistics)`

which one the correct way?

but seems 3 ways not call statistics

Comment: What do you mean by _not call statistics_?

Comment: statistics not called

Comment: I understand this part but how do you determine that? A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be in place.